# Need help for a specific MySQL query used in a PHP loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, while-loop

The main code which i use is

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    echo $row["user_id"];
    $new    = "[grade uid=\"{$row["user_id"]}\" value=\"{$groupgrade}\" format=\"{$groupformat}\" prv_comment=\"{$groupprivatecomment}\" pub_comment=\"{$grouppubliccomment}\"] ";
    $sqq    = "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='$new' WHERE meta_key='grade' AND post_id= $post_id ";
    $result = mysql_query($sqq);
    echo "grade has been updated";
}
```

Which affects the rows in table wp_postmeta as shown in the picture on the link [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkUiz.jpg] Where all the variables undefined here are defined before this para .

What i actually want that user id must be different in different rows.
The only thing happening in this loop is that each uid from the array gets written in all the rows one after the other and only the last uid persists finally which is 3 in the diagram  but i only want that each uid should come separately i.e., differnt uid for diff. meta_id . Please help

REGARDING CODE
$result1 fetches an array of userids from a defined mysql function and rest variables are user defined.
I am kinda new to php and to programming so please help

Comment: Your question isn't all that clear. Could you supply the `$result1` query, a sample (three rows) of its results? I suspect that the "different uid for different meta_id" issue needs to be solved there.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you post code here to ask about it, please properly format it so it is easy to read. Use the preview function. I now edited it for you, but take care next time.

Comment: How many distinct `user_id`'s are in `wp_postmeta`? Are there multiple rows with `user_id = 3 `?

Comment: Does it matter which row gets which uid?

Comment: `WHERE meta_key='grade' AND post_id= $post_id` doesn't use anything in `$row`, so it's updating the same database rows each time through the loop.

Comment: @Barmar no it does not matter which row gets which uid but here same uid gets alloted to all the rows which is my main problem

Comment: @lserni the query you asked for is  $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM  wp_bp_groups_members WHERE  group_id = $groupid AND user_title != 'Group Admin' ";
 $result1 = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: The UPDATE query can't update all rows. It only updates the rows with meta_key='grade' and post_id=$post_id. Is this inside a loop that updates multiple `$post_id`s?

Comment: @Barmar No only a specific post_id . I actually need same post id for multiple rows having diff. uid and also note post_id which is a user input variable.

Comment: There's no way that query can update rows with a different post_id. There must be something you're not showing us.

Comment: @Barmar query only updates rows with same post_id i.e the one entered by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now that I understand your problem (you confused me by saying that "all rows" were being updated, you just mean all rows with this `post_id`), I think this is the answer:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT meta_id FROM wp_postmeta where meta_key='grade' AND post_id = $post_id";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) && ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))) {
    echo $row2["meta_id"], ' => ', $row["user_id"];
    $new    = "[grade uid=\"{$row["user_id"]}\" value=\"{$groupgrade}\" format=\"{$groupformat}\" prv_comment=\"{$groupprivatecomment}\" pub_comment=\"{$grouppubliccomment}\"] ";
    $sqq    = "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='$new' WHERE meta_key='grade' AND post_id= $post_id AND meta_id = {$row2["meta_id"]}";
    $result = mysql_query($sqq);
    echo " grade has been updated";
}
```

The new `$sql2` query gets each `meta_id`, and updates each row with a different `user_id` from `$result11`.

Comment: I think this was the solution I was really looking for . But now I am stuck at another problem in this file.

Comment: the thing is for   echo $row2["meta_id"], ' => ', $row["user_id"]; I am getting 51 => grade has been updated101 => grade has been updated which means  $row["user_id"] is coming empty also there is no user id which comes in table after the update query .

Comment: I've fixed my code, it needed parentheses around the assignments in the while-loop.

Comment: I noticed something else in your pastebin: You have an extra fetch from `$result1` on line 40. So that first row will be skipped in this loop unless you use `mysql_data_seek()` to reset. I suspect it was just a debugging statement, since all you do is print the row.

Comment: Thanks for the help man!!!! really saved me .... and that was a debugging statement ......

Comment: anyways do we need to close a question.... as you said above.... but i cannot find any option to close... ??

Answer (score 2):

The `question` is not very clear and it's `WordPress` related and you didn't add `WordPress` tag in your question. Anyways, `WordPress` has it's own function to handle post meta. In your loop you are trying to update post meta manually but it's possible to do that using WordPress' [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function. The syntax is given bellow

```
<?php update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value); ?>
```

In this case you can use following code

```
<?php update_post_meta($post_id, 'grade', $new); ?>
```

Here `$post_id` will be your post id which you want to update.

Comment: Actually i want different uid for different rows . can this function  run in my while loop ?. The thing is, i am not that friendly with wordpress to tried to do this task  manually

Comment: @user1924981, you can run this function inside your loop using different `id` each time.

Answer (score 0):

your code is to work around this `$row["user_id"]`

- if it same user who posted then the result will be true 3
- if this variable is from other query then u must look to this query how u getting this `user_id` or , publish it in your question , to  see why it comes only 3.
- its better to make a column for `user_id` to insert data specialy for that user.
- `$row["user_id"]` is beeing a warning variable to sql injection , so it must be escaped by `mysql_real_escape_string()`